# What types of files can I upload with the Wordpress Uploader?

Tags: uploads, file-manager

I have a domain with Wordpress 3.4.2 installed on it. (This is NOT a Wordpress.com site)

What kind of files can I upload? I know .jpeg, .gif, .png, .mp3, etc. are accepted, but where can I find a complete list of the accepted file types?

Basically, what can I upload via this screen: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files  :

**WordPress supports uploading the following file types:**

> Images
>
> .jpg .jpeg .png .gif
>
> Documents
>
> .pdf (Portable Document Format; Adobe Acrobat) .doc, .docx (Microsoft
>   Word Document) .ppt, .pptx, .pps, .ppsx (Microsoft PowerPoint
>   Presentation) .odt (OpenDocument Text Document) .xls, .xlsx (Microsoft
>   Excel Document)
>
> Audio
>
> .mp3 .m4a .ogg .wav
>
> Video
>
> .mp4, .m4v (MPEG-4) .mov (QuickTime) .wmv (Windows Media Video) .avi
>   .mpg .ogv (Ogg) .3gp (3GPP) .3g2 (3GPP2)
>
> Not all web hosts permit these files to be uploaded. Also, they may not
>   permit large file uploads. If you are having issues, please check with
>   your host first.

That bottom note means that you may be limited on the size of file uploads via your or your web host's php.ini file, and file type uploads may also be limited in php.ini or .htaccess, depending on what you have configured or what your web host has configured.